# How can I write upside down real numbers symbol ($\mathbb{R}$)?

Tags: math-mode, rotating, text-decorations

How can I write `$\mathbb{R}$` upside down? And, in general, `\mathbb` letters...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `\umathbb{R}` for ***u***​pside down
2. `\rmathbb{R}` for ***r***​eflected
3. `\fmathbb{R}` for ***f***​lipped

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\umathbb}[1]{{\mathpalette\dude@umathbb{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dude@umathbb}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\rotatebox{180}{$\m@th#1\mathbb{#2}$}}%
}
\newcommand{\rmathbb}[1]{{\mathpalette\dude@rmathbb{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dude@rmathbb}[2]{%
  \scalebox{-1}[1]{$\m@th#1\mathbb{#2}$}%
}
\newcommand{\fmathbb}[1]{{\mathpalette\dude@fmathbb{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dude@fmathbb}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1\mathbb{#2}$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\umathbb{R}B$ $A\rmathbb{R}B$ $A\fmathbb{R}B$

$X_{\umathbb{R}}$ $X_{\rmathbb{R}}$ $X_{\fmathbb{R}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Odd. I would usually consider "upside down" to mean "reflected about a horizontal axis," but it appears that by this definition, it means "rotated by 180 degrees."

Comment: @jpmc26 There were two possible interpretations of the OP's request, so I provided both.

Comment: @jpmc26, personally I consider it a 180 rotation such that it can be *read* upside down (at least the individual glyphs can be), but I can see your point of view also :)

Answer (score 5):

To rotate upside down:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

X\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathbb{R}$}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Supports smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\umathbb[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\SavedStyle\mathbb{#1}$}}}
\newcommand\rmathbb[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{\scalebox{-1}[1]{$\SavedStyle\mathbb{#1}$}}}
\newcommand\fmathbb[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\SavedStyle\mathbb{#1}$}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
 A\mathbb{R}B\quad A\umathbb{R}B\quad A\rmathbb{R}B\quad A\fmathbb{R}B
\]
\[
 X_{\mathbb{R}} X_{\umathbb{R}} X_{\rmathbb{R}} X_{\fmathbb{R}}
\]
\[
 \mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}}}\quad
 \umathbb{R}_{\umathbb{R}_{\umathbb{R}}}\quad
 \rmathbb{R}_{\rmathbb{R}_{\rmathbb{R}}}\quad
 \fmathbb{R}_{\fmathbb{R}_{\fmathbb{R}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]